# Adding conversion method to Numeric causes SystemStackError

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to add conversion methods to the Numeric class but when I run the following lines of code I get a SystemStackError

```
puts 5.dollars.in(:euros)  # => 6.5
puts 1.dollar.in(:yen)
```

Here is my Numeric class

```
class Numeric
  @@conversion_hash = {:dollar => {:yen => 0.013, :euros => 1.292, :rupees => 0.019}}

   def method_missing(method_id)
     name = method_id.to_s
     if name =~ /^dollar|yen|euros|rupee|$/
       self.send(name + 's')
     else
       super # pass the buck to superclass
     end
   end

   def dollars()
    puts "Called Dollars method"
    @current_currency = :dollar
    return self
   end

   def in(key)
     if @@conversion_hash.has_key?(@current_currency)
       puts "Current currency: #{@current_currency}"
       conversion_rate = @@conversion_hash[@current_currency]
       puts "Current conversion rate: #{conversion_rate}"
       if conversion_rate.has_key?(key)
         puts "we have that key"
         puts"What am I? #{self}"
         rate = conversion_rate[key]
         puts "Rate to multiply by #{rate}"
        return self.to_int * conversion_rate[key]
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting infinite recursion in your `method_missing` because your regex isn't quite right. Try changing the line:

```
if name =~ /^dollar|yen|euros|rupee|$/
```

to:

```
if name =~ /^dollar|yen|euros|rupee$/
```

That extra `|` is causing anything to match the regex, so any other method is recursing with a continually extending suffix of `s`.

In this case it looks like `puts` seems to be trying to call `to_ary` when it's trying to determine the type its argument. I'm not exactly sure why it's not just using `respond_to?` though - it's deep in the C internals so I don't really know what's happening.

Comment: Or just use `%w[dollars yen euros rupees].include? name` instead of the regex. He also has some plural/singular problems in his regex but that's the next bug...

Comment: @muistooshort That's probably better than a regex here, but at least we've located the source of the recursion. I'm scratching my head trying to think why `puts` is calling `to_ary` instead of just using `respond_to?`. I've traced the calls through to `rb_check_convert_type` in `object.c` but I'm getting out of my depth. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head. Could it be the string interpolation? Are you sure `puts` is the one calling `to_ary`?

Comment: @muistooshort As far as I can tell from using `caller`, it's `puts`. Although thinking about it, if `to_ary` (or any `to_xxx` methods) are defined dynamically in some way (e.g. in `method_missing`) then the only way to be sure the object doesn't respond to it would be to try and call it - `respond_to?` can't necessarily be relied on in all cases, so perhaps it does make sense. I might have to go spelunking in the source and look at the `rb_check_xxx_type` methods.

Comment: Have a look at `rb_io_puts` in `io.c`, in some cases that will call `rb_check_array_type` and that's just `rb_check_convert_type(ary, T_ARRAY, "Array", "to_ary")`. I would expect `rb_io_puts` to jump straight to the `string:` label inside the loop though.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution overcomplicated.
- You don't need to modify method_missing. Armando version works fine.
- You should simple dollar definition to hash plus
- find the way to call method_missing again from method in(this is your homework). 
Working solution have only 1 line of code + 2 lines def surronding.